# when i write node -v no error comes but when i write npm -v then eror comes

Tags: node.js, npm

C:\Users\USER>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
8.5.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This might have something to do with the content of what's in the `npm-cli.js` file. Does that file have a slew of logic in it or is it small enough to fit in the question with an [edit]?